# Роль в предложении "да" и "нет": "На нет и суда нет", "проголосовали за?

Tags: синтаксис

Какую роль в предложении играют выделенные слова? На **нет** и суда **нет**. Сколько человек проголосовали **за**?

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае нет - это дополнение, член предложения. Во втором - сказуемое, выраженное словом нет. Предложение односоставное безличное.

Answer (score 0):

Проголосовали (как?) "за" (обстоятельство образа действия)